# Debian: exim, Maildir and mail

Tags: debian, exim, mailx, maildir

I have `exim` installed and configured as "internet site; mail is sent and received directly using SMTP". Mail is stored in `/home/*user*/Maildir` and it is really there. I can send and receive mail globally and internally, but my Debian Wheezy's `mail` program isn't showing any of it.

Does `mail` support Maildir format at all? The messages are there, I can access them via `mutt -f Maildir`. It's convenient to see a number of new e-mails at SSH logon.

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/a/47706

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, @jordanm gave me a right direction, but information is scattered across the Net, so I think it is worth to post some kind of guide myself.

1. Install `mailutils` and `heirloom-mailx` packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mailutils heirloom-mailx
   ```
2. Update alternatives for `mailx` — choose `/usr/bin/heirloom-mailx`:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config mailx
   ```
3. The last part: update 3 files in `/etc/pam.d/`. There is a string in each of three following files, which starts with `session optional pam_mail.so`, update it with the following values:

   **/etc/pam.d/login**:

   ```
   session optional pam_mail.so dir=~/Maildir standard
   ```

   **/etc/pam.d/su**:

   ```
   session optional pam_mail.so dir=~/Maildir nopen
   ```

   **/etc/pam.d/sshd**:

   ```
   session optional pam_mail.so dir=~/Maildir standard
   ```

Sources: [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/47706/143724) and [this blog post](http://erikimh.com/debianubuntu-mailutils-and-maildir/).